# Uploading more array fields to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore in my app, and every minute I want to upload new fields to my array. It can be done by uploading fields on by one, but that increases the number of writes to database a lot. Also it can be done with rewriting whole array each time, but that produce tons of unnecessary transferred data.
I tried to pass the array with new data to arrayUnion function like this:

```
//function called every minute
//newLocations contains about 30 Geopoints 
private void uploadLocations(List<GeoPoint> newLocations){
documentReference.update("locations",FieldValue.arrayUnion(newLocations));
}
```

But it doesn't work, because the function takes the newLocations array as one field to upload and throws error, because nested arrays are disabled.

Locations field is an array of geopoints:

[image: Firebase screenshot]

Is there any proper way to upload more fields to firestore array at the same time?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot to see the `locations` array.

Comment: There's not enough code here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please show the complete, minimal code that reproduces the issue, include how you build `newLocations`, and the error message you get.

Comment: I don't have any error, or issue, I just wanted to know, if there is some way to upload more fields  to firestore array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` only allows for values to be used as parameters, not an entire array, however there are a couple of ways that you could make it work.

For the first one, I am not sure if this is implemented in Android, but you could try to use `arrayUnion.apply()`:

```
documentReference.update("locations",FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply(null,newLocations));
```

Basically what this does is that it 'applys' a single array of arguments to the function (rather than comma separated arguments) and invokes it. I am positive that this works for Javascript so maybe this is also implemented for Android, worth giving a try.

If this does not work, what you could do is convert your `newLocations` to a `String[]`, which should be acceptable as parameters for `FieldValue.arrayUnion()`, you could do it like this:

```
String[] strArray = newLocations.toArray(new String[0]);
documentReference.update("locations",FieldValue.arrayUnion(strArray));
```

What is happenning in the code above is that the `toArray()` method without passing any argument returns `Object[]`. So you have to pass an array as an argument, which will be filled with the data from the list, and returned.

Comment: Unfortunately FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply() isn't possible in android/java, but it would be exactly what I was asking for. The second solution is probably the best one I tried, thank you.